# Qu'est-ce qu'un train direct ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs, transports

Suivant le *Trésor de la langue française*, un train [direct](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/direct) est un « train qui ne s'arrête qu'à des stations principales » (un [express](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/express), en d'autres termes), citation de Zola à l'appui. Pourtant, à la [SNCF](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soci%C3%A9t%C3%A9_nationale_des_chemins_de_fer_fran%C3%A7ais), on parle de train direct entre deux gares pour signifier qu'il n'y a pas de changement à faire, et de train sans arrêt entre deux gares pour signifier, justement, qu'il n'y a pas d'arrêt en chemin. À la [RATP](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9gie_autonome_des_transports_parisiens), par contre, les annonces enregistrées parlent de *train direct* entre deux gares pour signifier qu'il n'y a pas d'arrêt.

Qu'en est-il ailleurs dans le monde francophone ? Y a-t-il une évolution historique du sens du mot *direct* ? Dans quels cas le mot *direct* (dans le cadre d'un moyen de transport) est-il compréhensible dans autre précision ?

Comment: Quand la SNCF parle de train direct, elle parle bien de train sans arrêt, par exemple [train direct Paris - Auvers-sur-Oise](http://www.transilien.com/web/site/accueil/plus_sur_transilien/en-savoir-plus/actualites/train-direct-auvers) dont le voyage d'environ 30 min est sans arrêt intermédiaire. En revanche, l'agence de voyage "voyages-sncf.com" emploie le terme "trajet direct" pour un trajet sans correspodance.

Comment: @rds Sur les grandes lignes, je crois entendre encore « sans arrêt » pour signaler qu'un train ne s'arrête pas. J'ai l'impression, peut-être fausse, que l'utilisation de « direct » dans ce sens en Île-de-France est récente.

Comment: L'exemple du direct Paris Auvers-sur-Oise n'est à mon avis pas pertinent parce qu'il est aussi direct dans le sens "sans correspondance", contrairement aux autres moyens de se rendre à Auvers-sur-Oise (avec changement) le reste du temps.

Answer (score 5):

Après avoir vérifié, "train direct" veut bien dire "sans arrêt". Ca s'applique aussi à un train sans correspondance, s'il ne fait pas d'autres arrêts.

Je pense que la confusion vient du fait que la SNCF utilise le terme "train" pour désigner un train, **ou un trajet**, ainsi que du fait qu'il n'y a pas de terme exact pour un "train sans correspondances", qui techniquement, fait aussi son trajet "direct".

Donc le terme "train direct" désigne un train qui ne s'arrête pas. Vivant en France, je l'ai toujours entendu/compris ainsi. Quand on parle du train direct "Lyon-Paris", on sait directement qu'il s'agit d'un train qui fait le trajet en direct, aucune question ne se pose.

Par contre, pour un train sans correspondance, n'ayant pas de terme **défini** pour "sans correspondances", on utilisera "direct", "sans arrêt", "sans correspondances", ou autres, pour tenter de se faire comprendre.

Comment: Vérifié où ? Parce que ma question porte sur l'usage, qui ne suit clairement pas toujours les dictionnaires. D'ailleurs, chez Zola, un train Lyon-Dijon-Paris serait un *direct* car il s'arrête peu ; j'ai l'impression que ce sens a disparu de l'usage (au profit d'*express*), même si on le trouve encore dans les dictionnaires.

Comment: Zola étant mort il y'a presque 110 ans, on peut en déduire qu'il prenait moins souvent le train, et que la question se posait moins. D'expérience, "un train direct" désigne un train qui ne s'arrête pas, et est compris comme tel. cf [Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_direct). Par contre, en cherchant plus, certains très longs trains (Paris-Moscou, Paris-Barcelone, Paris-Venise) sont appelés trains directs, mais ont quand même quelques escales. D'où le "train direct" ferait référence à un train ayant le moins d'arrêts possibles, si possible aucun.

Comment: Quand on parle de « train direct Paris–Moscou », ou plus encore de « voiture directe Paris–Moscou », le sens est « sans changement ». Il est clair que plusieurs sens sont utilisés. Le but de ma question est de dépatouiller ces usages, pas d'affirmer qu'il y en a un seul qui est correct (ce qui est n'est manifestement pas le cas).

Comment: Oui, je "pensais" qu'il y en avait un de correct, désolé. Après réflexion/relecture/recherche, je dirais que l'on dit "train direct" lorsque le train est "plus direct que l'on pourrait le penser", donc lorsqu'il est nécessaire de le mentionner. On mentionne "direct Lyon-Paris" lorsque le train est habituellement avec arrêts, mais que ce n'est pas le cas ici. De même, on dira "direct Paris-Moscou" lorsque le train n'a qu'un arrêt, alors qu'il a habituellement plusieurs arrêts/changements nécessaires. Par contre, n'ayant pas de source définie, il ne peut s'agire que de mon impression de natif.

Comment: Au sens "express", on trouve maintenant l'expression "semi-direct", par exemple dans cette [annonce du STIF](http://www.stif.info/IMG/pdf/Deliberation_2009-0401_relative_a_Transilien_2010.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Le sens de *direct* a évolué entre Zola et maintenant. Maintenant, comme tu le dis justement dans ta remarque, on utilise plus *express*.
Après, pourquoi le site web voyage-sncf utilise plus *direct* pour « sans correspondance » alors que la RATP utilise le sens de « sans arrêts intermédiaires ». C'est à mon avis parce que ce n'est pas destiné aux mêmes personnes.

Dans le premier cas, les gens cherchent un trajet (qui peut avoir des correspondances) et savoir s'il y a des arrêts intermédiaires importe peu.
Dans le second cas, les gens connaissent déjà l’itinéraire, et par construction ne feront pas de correspondance. Ici le terme « direct » est en fait une appellation un niveau supérieur aux trains « express ». Il y a les omnibus (tous les arrêts), les express (quelques arrêts), les directs (aucun arrêt).

Comment: Je ne vois pas d'où viendrait cette distinction entre la SNCF et la RATP. Il y a aussi des correspondances dans le métro.

Comment: oui mais les métros font tous les arrêts de la ligne. c'est pour cela, en metro, tu aura plus tendance a dire _direct_ comme sans correspondance.

Comment: @francois c'est inexact. Certaines lignes de métro ne marquent pas l'arrêt à certaines stations (travaux, manifestations). Le message est toujours conçu pour être très clair: le métro ne marquera pas l'arrêt à la station Concorde, et sera direct ... C'est aussi le cas tout le temps sur les lignes RER (ratp/SNCF) en dehors de Paris où la desserte change pour chaque train. L'objectif est de prévenir les personnes à l'intérieur. Sur les trains de grande ligne, il n'est pas possible d'énoncer toutes les stations sautées: c'est donc direct jusqu'à ... la suivante.